# Is there an Om Writer-style front end for gvim or macvim

Tags: macos, vim, macvim

Here's my dilemma: I love the features of vim, but I also like using Om Writer for its' approach to enhancing relaxation and creativity. For those unfamiliar, Om Writer blanks out all other programs, fills the screen with a complete blank page and has music and sounds that play. It even has the _ character as the cursor to avoid the wall style | character at the end of the line!

So I use Om Writer for some things, but I sure miss all of the neat things you can do from the keyboard in vim. Om Writer requires a lot of mousing around. So I have looked around and found nothing, but I was wondering if there might be such a thing as an Om Writer-style front end for Vim?

And if not, how difficult might such a thing be to program for MacVim on Snow Leopard? (I am at the kindergarten level as a programmer, but I would considering paying someone to do it if the job wasn't terribly involved.)

Comment: There is a full-screen mode in MacVim as far as I'm aware. How about that?

Answer (score 2):

I remembered [one plugin](http://projects.mikewest.org/vimroom/) but a quick google returned [two](http://www.laktek.com/2012/09/05/distraction-free-writing-with-vim/) [other](http://paulrouget.com/e/vimdarkroom/) projects. Playing music, though, is kind of the absolute opposite of Vim's philosophy but nothing stops you from launching a playlist in iTunes.

And I'll spare you my rant about those "distraction-free" editors.

Answer (score 0):

I second romainl's recommendation of [vimroom](http://projects.mikewest.org/vimroom/); I've tried it and found it quite nice. Additionally, the [shell.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3123) has a fullscreen mode that blanks out window title, taskbar, etc.